# Как запустить функцию в потоке (DLLMain)?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, dll, c++11

Приветствую. Есть некая функция, которая получает хеш-сумму файла (exe) и записывает ее в файл. Она запущена в потоке, но приложение откуда она запускается - крашит. Хотелось бы узнать как правильно запустить функцию в потоке, чтобы приложение не крашилось.

```
void initialize()
{
    string buffer;
    thread t(calclulateHash, ref(buffer));
    t.detach();
}
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            initialize();
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Что такое - `ref(buffer)`? Вы понимаете, что эта строчка делает?

Comment: Вы пробовали писать то же самое в обычном консольном приложении? При чем тут вообще DllMain?

Answer (score 4):

Таким образом как вы делаете, делать нельзя. В `DllMain` [нельзя запускать потоки (или проводить синхронизацию)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx).

Вынесите запуск потока в отдельную функцию и вызывайте её не из `DllMain`, а из другого места.

---

Одной из возможных причин проблемы является синхронизация всех вызовов `DllMain`: каждый её вызов ждёт окончания других. Если вы запускаете поток, это приводит к попытке рекурсивного вызова с флагом `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` (не `PROCESS`), что немедленно приводит к проблемам.

`DllMain` — это специальная; очень ограниченная функция, принципы, распространяемые на обычные функции, тут не работают.

---

Ну и интересна сигнатура функции `calculateHash`, конечно.

Comment: Можете развернуть мысль, не понятно ограничение по запуску потоков из DllMain

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Это ограничение операционной системы.

Comment: Ну там же "should", в действительности вполне дергается CreateThread (хотя и bad practice, да). ( Creating a thread can work if you do not synchronize with other threads, but it is risky.)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Ну вот сказано «нельзя, могут быть проблемы», и вот как раз и проблемы :-)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Наверняка стандартная библиотека проводит какую-то синхронизацию, которая строго запрещена в `DllMain`. Там же не прямой вызов `CreateThread`, с которым проблемы всего лишь «могут быть».

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, проблемы две 1) мьютекс в `LoadLibrary` и потенциальный deadlock на нём и 2) недозагрузка части библиотек на момент вызова нашей `DllMain` (среди которых может оказаться и стандартная библиотека C++).

Comment: @Arhad Тем не менее это не ограничение на запуск потока из `DllMain`, а ограничение возможностей, доступных в этом потоке.

Answer (score 2):

Грубо говоря, локальная переменная

```
string buffer;
```

передается в поток по ссылке (благодаря `std::ref`):

```
thread t(calclulateHash, ref(buffer));
```

каковой поток отсоединяется и выполняется и, как я понимаю, потом пытается писать в `buffer`

```
t.detach();
```

которого уже нет, потому что функция, в которой он объявлен, давно закончилась...

Зачем вам вообще считать нечто, что вы никак не используете?